# Sticky full header & announcement bar Shopify using Expanse theme

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, shopify

I just want to make my full header and the announcement bar sticky after some scrolling. Here is the code that just sticky the navigation bar only see the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/3aekAh1W9XTF This is my store front-end URL: https://uniqaya.com/ Below is the code that I have found from one of the forums but it does not meet my requirements.

```js
<script>
     let navEl = document.querySelector('.site-header__element--top');
     let menuEl = document.querySelector('.site-header__element--sub');
     window.onscroll = function() {
      if(window.innerWidth > 768){
        if (document.body.scrollTop > navEl.offsetHeight || document.documentElement.scrollTop > navEl.offsetHeight) {
           navEl.style.top = `-${navEl.offsetHeight}px`;
           menuEl.style.position = "fixed";
           menuEl.style.top = "0px";
        } else {
           navEl.style.top = "0px";
           menuEl.style.top = `${navEl.offsetHeight}px`;
           menuEl.style.position = "absolute";
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
.header-item--compress-nav {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
.header-wrapper--compressed .site-header__element--sub{
  transform: translateY(0) !important;
  display: block !important;
}
}
```

The above code just makes the navigation menu bar sticky only. But I need the full header bar along with the announcement bar sticky on some scrolling. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your issue is comming from navEl.style.top = `-${navEl.offsetHeight}px`; & navEl.style.top = `${navEl.offsetHeight}px`; that are setting the position after the scroll. Have you tried removing those ? If the top header doesn't appear anymore just remove the visibility hidden in the css too

Comment: @Nocil I have comment both the things as you mentioned earlier but did not works. It remains the same!

Comment: Will try to look deeper into it

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but it's the closer i can get for your problem
Hope it's what you are looking for otherwise i don't think i can help you more

```
let navEl = document.querySelector('.site-header__element--top');
let menuEl = document.querySelector('.site-header__element--sub');

window.onscroll = function() {
   if(window.innerWidth > 768){
      if (document.body.scrollTop > navEl.offsetHeight || document.documentElement.scrollTop > navEl.offsetHeight) {
         navEl.style.top = `0px`;
         navEl.style.position = `fixed`;
         navEl.style.width = `100%`;
         menuEl.style.position = "fixed";
         menuEl.style.top = `${navEl.offsetHeight}px`;
      } else {
         navEl.style.top = "34px";
         navEl.style.position = `fixed`;
         menuEl.style.top = `${navEl.offsetHeight}px`;
         menuEl.style.position = "absolute";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It works for homepage but it is overlapped on product page with its description section see screenshot: https://prnt.sc/HSunmPFBGxC7

Comment: mate please help we are so close.